# WebBrowser Refresh - Internet Explorer needs to resend the information

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, browser, webbrowser-control

I have a problem with `WebBrowser` control. When page is being refreshed (even if JavaScript caused it), it shows me the message:

> To display the webpage again, Internet Explorer needs to resend the information you've previously submitted. If you were making a purchase, you should click Cancel to avoid a duplicate transaction. Otherwise, click retry to display the webpage again.

How to hide this message?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this
window.location = window.location; 
it does refresh the page without the IE message, however, it loads the application from page 1 if you have multiple pages. so give it a try.